# Give the asker the power to delete answers

Tags: feature-request

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Provision to delete answer to your question](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/138393/provision-to-delete-answer-to-your-question)

Give the asker the power to delete or suppress comments and answers in the first 24 hours of the answer being posted. I have had some smartass unhelpful comments and answers posted on questions I have asked many times.

Comment: This was asked just yesterday, and shot down real bad: http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/138393/provision-to-delete-answer-to-your-question You can flag the smartass unhelpful comments for deletion and we'll gladly take care of them.

Comment: Do you mean within 24 hours of posting the *question*?

Comment: Delete your question, run and never look back. I requested same feature yesterday, look what they did to it : http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/138393/provision-to-delete-answer-to-your-question

Comment: wow..I guess we both are seeing that SO is becoming a youtube (comments) and yahoo answers. I guess being arrogant really does pay on the internet. I will try that strategy on my next project.

Comment: Your tone already shows that. "Give the asker" (no "Please","I'd like to", "It would be nice if"),  you want the system to do as you please because you want, your questions I saw are almost more in the form of "this is what I need, I'm waiting". These are invites for snarky comments (which sometimes are more helpful than you think)

Answer (score 15):

Let's ignore the fact (for a moment) that what you propose was already suggested around 24 hours ago and was extremely unpopular.

You have a history of asking questions - [299 at current count](https://stackoverflow.com/users/184773/luke101?tab=questions&sort=newest). If you find you are repeatedly getting *smartass and unhelpful comments and answers* then maybe it is your question or style that is provoking it? Comments [like this one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11303894/asp-net-mvc-hierarchy-builder-for-categories) may annoy you and seem unhelpful, but it is a legitimate question showing that maybe you have missed a step (not to mention asking for recommendations seldom makes a good question, and you have a history of asking that type of question).

Comment: Gah - answers like this make me wish you had won the last mod election.  Well said.

Comment: Brilliant--getting to the crux of it all. Without snark.