# Why are there down votes on Meta?

Tags: discussion, down-votes, meta

Why are people so eager to exercise downvotes? Isn't Meta supposed to be a more general discourse on a broader range of topics? Isn't it an opportunity to exchange dialogue with the SO community?

Edit: 
yes but unfortunately, practically it's the same users, as SO, so it ended up being the same culture, by default, rather than by reflection.

I [read a relevant post on the subject](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/270/the-meaning-of-down-votes-in-meta-vs-stackoverflow?rq=1), but again, what I see is *very different*. There is no open platform for discussion on general user points without incurring downvotes.

Comment: Related: [Does it make sense to have a negative rep cap for Meta posts?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/195145/does-it-make-sense-to-have-a-negative-rep-cap-for-meta-posts)

Comment: Thta's not its only purpose, no. One of its main purposes is to discuss feature requests, for which voting is essential.

Comment: Sure, but that doesn't mean all questions are good questions. They can be poorly researched, dupes of dupes of dupes, terribly unclear, or when it's a feature request, it can be a horrible idea.

Comment: @Bart inception dupes?

Comment: http://tvtropes.org/pmwiki/pmwiki.php/Main/SelfFulfillingProphecy

Comment: We're not really a forum here -- Meta is a Q&A site; it just so happens that because of the subject matter (Stack Exchange as a community and a platform) we can have opinionated answers -- unlike Stack Overflow, which specializes in objective and factual knowledge.

Comment: Also related: [A Proposal for More Constructive Downvoting on Meta: Express Disagreement by Answering the Question](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/193884/a-proposal-for-more-constructive-downvoting-on-meta-express-disagreement-by-ans)

Comment: Reading the first paragraph of this question, I immediately wonder why these two things are mutually exclusive. Why can't we downvote things as a way of exchanging dialogue with the community? Or perhaps I should say: that's what I do here.

Answer (score 17):

I'll share my point of view as a long time member here on Meta.

Votes, both up and down, are the way of expressing yourself without having to use words. When you see idea you either agree with or disagree with, you vote.

Now let's assume there will be no votes on Meta. People will have to write in order to express themselves, many times having to repeat what others already said or just write "yes, I agree" or "no, I don't agree" which will cause huge clutter and tons of noise, not to mention privacy is gone.

Think that's enough reason why votes are important here on Meta, no less than they're important on the main site.

Comment: And even so, we're generally not at a loss for words here. :)

Comment: @Bart very true, but many posts (both Questions and Answers) end up with lots of votes and few comments.

Comment: Oh sure, votes tend to outweigh contributions. Sometimes significantly so. But silence or lack of points of view is rarely the case. (Not that you were implying that).