# Can we get versioned tags for Google Analytics?

Tags: feature-request, stack-overflow, tags

Currently if you're digging for answers regarding Google Maps on Android on SO, it's easy to separate relevant questions from irrelevant ones by including the proper version tag:

- [google-maps-api-2](/questions/tagged/google-maps-api-2)
- [google-maps-api-3](/questions/tagged/google-maps-api-3)

Similarly on Android, there have been three versions of SDK for Google Analytics, but the only tags for these sorts of questions are:

- [google-analytics](/questions/tagged/google-analytics)
- [google-analytics-api](/questions/tagged/google-analytics-api) (Which doesn't even apply to using an SDK)

Trying to find answers to issues surrounding Google Analytics on Android is quite difficult, because most of the questions are referencing one of the older APIs, don't make that obvious, and the newest SDK changed things up quite a bit over the older versions.

I don't have enough reputation to create tags there myself, but it seems like at the minimum, a [google-analytics-sdk-3](/questions/tagged/google-analytics-sdk-3) would be a useful tag to have.

Comment: As I am pretty new to Meta, I'd love to hear from you if you downvote me, so I can do better here.

Comment: What is so special about version 3? Does it brakes backward comptability? (btw: [voting on meta is different](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/195154/why-are-there-down-votes-on-meta))

Comment: Version three introduced a completely new `EasyTracker` class, but leaves totally ambiguous when/whether you should use it, and how it differs from the older `Tracker` class. Even their own online documentation for SDK 3 intermixes using the two, and so spending time on their documentation tends to leave more questions than answers. Likewise, since there's no version information on SO questions, one can really only ascertain whether an answer on SO is relevant by trying to do date comparisons to SDK release dates.

Comment: And thanks for the link about voting, I read that a while ago but had forgotten about the difference.

Comment: If that is the only difference I don't see a reason for that tag now. If you find more/some questions that would be tagged with this new tag as an example I might change my position.

Answer (score 1):

> I don't have enough reputation to create tags there myself, but it seems like at the minimum, a google-analytics-sdk-3 would be a useful tag to have.

I checked someone has already created a tag for latest Google Analytics. It is in same format as you were looking `google-analytics-v4` now I think it is ok.

You can check this. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/google-analytics-v4